# How to create a custom suffix rule to use a header in another directory?

Tags: qt, makefile, autotools, automake, moc

I have a *Makefile.am* like the following to compile MOC files for Qt using automake.

```
bin_PROGRAMS = test

test_qtheaders = window.h

test_moc_sources = $(test_qtheaders:.h=_moc.cpp)

test_SOURCES =               \
    main.cpp                 \
    main-window.cpp          \
    window.cpp               \
    $(test_moc_sources)

test_CPPFLAGS = -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I$(QT5_INCL) -I$(QT5_INCL)/QtWidgets -I$(QT5_INCL)/QtCore

test_LDFLAGS = -L/usr/lib64 -L/usr/local/lib64 -L/usr/local/lib -L$(QT5_LIBS)

test_LDADD = -lrt -lQt5Core -lQt5Gui -lQt5Widgets

SUFFIXES = .h _moc.cpp

# this suffix rule is not finding the headers from src/includes/gui
.h_moc.cpp:
    $(QT_MOC) -o $@ $(test_CPPFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $<
```

I get the following error.

```
make[4]: *** No rule to make target 'window_moc.cpp', needed by 'test-window_moc.o'.  Stop.
```

My directory structure is as follows:

```
myproj
|- configure.ac
|- Makefile.am
|- ...
` src
    |- Makefile.am
    |- includes
    |    `- gui 
    |        |- main-window.h
    |        `- window.h    // file required to generate *.cpp.
    |
    `- gui
        |- Makefile.am
        |- main.cpp
        |- main-window.cpp
        `- window.cpp   // output of MOC, does not yet exist.
```

If I place the main-window.h file in *src/gui* directory, the MOC will find it and  build. Adding the *src/includes/gui* path to the test_CPPFLAGS doesn't do it. I also tried adding *../../includes/gui/$<* to the command, but to no avail.

So my question is, how does one tell the suffix rule where to find a file if it's in an outside directory of the Makefile.am?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to create a custom suffix rule to use a header in another directory?

You can't.  It is inherent in the nature of suffix rules that they apply to targets having a corresponding prerequisite in the same directory. It cannot be otherwise because `make` doesn't know anything about path structure.  That is, although target and prerequisite names can contain directory components, `make` just treats them as flat strings (which nevertheless does the right thing when it passes such strings to the C library or interpolates them into shell commands).<sup>*</sup>

In particular, this suffix rule ...

> ```
> .h_moc.cpp:
>     $(QT_MOC) -o $@ $(test_CPPFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $<
> ```

..., interpreted in light of your suffix declarations, describes how to build targets with names of the form *<prefix>*_moc.cpp from corresponding prerequisites named *<same_prefix>*.h. Supposing that the target you want to build is actually `gui/window_moc.cpp` (not `gui/window.cpp` as shown in the question), the relevant prefix would be `gui/window`.  The corresponding prerequisite would then be `gui/window.h`, and that's simply not the same thing as `include/gui/window.h`.

If you want to build targets in `gui/` from sources in `include/gui/`, sticking to portable `make` syntax and features according to Autotools recommendations, then you will need to write ordinary target rules, not suffix rules:

```
gui/window_moc.cpp: include/gui/window.h
    $(QT_MOC) -o $@ $(test_CPPFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $<
```

I presume that you want a suffix rule to avoid writing multiple regular target rules, and that's a perfectly reasonable idea. But it simply is not an option if you require the source and target layout described in the question.

---

<sup>*</sup> The Autotools are largely irrelevant here, because the main thing they do with custom rules appearing in your `Makefile.am` is pass them through, unchanged, to the final makefile(s).